# WebFont won't show

Tags: html, css, fonts

So I would like to set a font for my webpage body, and so I created a core.css file with this code:

```
@font-face {
font-family: Bebas; 
src: url('../fonts/bebas-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
     url('../fonts/bebas-webfont.eot') format('embedded-opentype'),
     url('../fonts/bebas-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
     url('../fonts/bebas-webfont.svg') format('svg');
font-weight: 700;
}

body{
background: url('../images/bg_1.png')repeat center center fixed; 
-webkit-background-size: cover;
-moz-background-size: cover;
-o-background-size: cover;
background-size: cover;
font-family: 'Bebas', serif;
}
```

But it doesn't seem to show up... not even when I try `<font face="bebas"></font>`... I tried this with another font and it worked, I have no idea of what is going on. The font files are in the right place.

**SOLUTION:**
As i was using 2 fonts i forgot to use two seperate @font-face {
once i separated them, worked like a charm

Comment: apparently is ok ... the urls are correct?

Comment: Are the fonts located in that location?

Comment: You should pretend you never heard of the `<font>` tag

Comment: Fonts are on public_html/fonts

Comment: Not enough information. We have no access to “public_html/fonts". And no HTML was included.

Comment: If one of the answers has solved the issue, it'd be good to accept it by clicking the tick just underneath the vote arrows. If they don't answer your question and you have solved the problem, please answer the question yourself (and accept it), instead of putting your solution in the question. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As i was using 2 fonts i forgot to use two seperate @font-face { once i separated them, worked like a charm

Answer (score 0):

what you are creating here is the font for weight=700. try to add font-eweight:700; to the body:

```
body{
background: url('../images/bg_1.png')repeat center center fixed; 
-webkit-background-size: cover;
-moz-background-size: cover;
-o-background-size: cover;
background-size: cover;
font-family: 'Bebas', serif;
font-weight:700;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check your browsers developer console. The answer is there.
Also, the path is relative to your css file and not your html. And font-weight is unnecessary here.

Comment: removed the weight, the path works fine for other fonts, its just this one... 4 warnigs pop up, none related to this css file